# display another web page cakephp 2

Tags: cakephp

Display another webpage into current page with different domain.

I'm already try any solution using iframe and javascript but still not solve.

But It shows with header, navbar. Everything is double now. So, I want to remove header and navbar from second page.

Answer (score 0):

I think that with a [JSON response](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) from an Ajax call you can resolve all your problems. For example let's assume you have your main page A with a specific `<div>` inside it used by the ajax call to pupulate your secondary page B.

Let's take an example:

```
<html>
    <head>[...]</head>
    <body>
        [...]
        <!-- 
        Using CSS you can style your div in order 
        to be "separated" from the main page style
        -->
        <div class="secondary-page"></div>
        [...]
    </body>
</html>
```

All you need is create a script using ajax to call a specific CakePHP controller which will return the html required for your "secondary-page" div.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'my/controller/url',
   [...],
   onSuccess: function(response) {
       // Response should contain a value with the html
       // In this way you can append it into your secondary-page div
       $('.secondary-page').append(response.pageBHTML);
   }
});
```

Comment: thank you with your suggestion, im new in cakephp, im still blur with you answer

Comment: I can help you with the theory... I've never used cakephp, just laravel, but with a quick look at the official documentation you can find everything you need for the controller part and a the view part

Comment: <html> code in .ctp, and than <script> in controller.